# Deleting duplicates from a database using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working in MySQL trying to insert a bunch of entries into a table. There are many semi-duplicates that I need to get rid of. I want to delete all of the semi-duplicates except for one. When I run the code below, it seems to be deleting everything that I don't want to be deleted by keeping only entries that have multiple semi-duplicates. How can I delete all but one of the semi-duplicates while also keeping the entries of everything else?

```
delete from t where (ColA, ColB, ColC) in 
(select * from (select ColA, ColB, ColC from t 
group by ColA, ColB, ColC having count(*) > 1) as t);
```

Comment: do you have any id column in your table?

Comment: I do, however the data I using can have a different primary key, while being a semi-duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Well, i don't think you can solve this without using a `where` 
But you can not operate a `SELECT WHERE` on a `DELETE` using the same table

Exemple from my database

```
delete from tb_test where idtb_test not in (
select idtb_test from tb_test T1 
WHERE T1.title in (select title from tb_test T2  group by T2.title having count(*) =1)
)
```

This query search for non-duplicates rows on col title and delete all the rows except the selected rows

Mysql Error :

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'tb_test' for update
>   in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to delete **almost** all rows which have a duplicate, and you don't care which one remains undeleted.
Also, as I understand - this table has primary key.

In that case, it can be done with this query:

```
delete test_table t3
where t3.id in (
    select t1.id
    from test_table t1, 
        (
            select col_a, col_b, col_c 
            from test_table 
            group by col_a, col_b, col_c 
            having count(*) > 1
        ) s1
    where t1.col_a = s1.col_a
        and t1.col_b = s1.col_b
        and t1.col_c = s1.col_c
        and t1.id != (
            select min(t2.id)
            from test_table t2
            where t1.col_a = t2.col_a
                and t1.col_b = t2.col_b
                and t1.col_c = t2.col_c
            group by col_a, col_b, col_c
        )
    )
```

Basically, this query deletes all row duplicates except for those with minimal ID, which is PK in my case.

PS: This works in Oracle DB, can't test in MySQL right now.

Comment: Almost correct. The Primary Key is always unique, but multiple other fields will be the same. I know that if all of the said fields are the same, then those duplicate entries can be deleted, minus the one that needs to stay.

Comment: Query in my answer does exactly that - for every set of rows with same col_a, col_b and col_c it deletes all of them, except for one with minimal Primary Key in that set.